# Does Liquibase supports JOIN in XML ChangeSet

Tags: xml, join, left-join, liquibase

Hi i am working with Liquibase for the first time and want to know if Liquibase supports JOINS between some table at least between two tables.

I want to use the XML ChangeSet but i cannot find any information about that.

Answer (score 2):

The standard Liquibase change commands generally do not support JOIN operations. If you have more complex SQL requirements, you have to fall back to using an `<sql>` tag for those changes.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: When would you use joins in a changeset? In my limited SQL repertoire I use JOINS only when I query the database but not when I create DB structure. Well maybe in VIEWs though - but other then that?.

Comment: I suppose liquibase is just for DB structure and not for migrations then... If a piece of software evolves, it is likely that you need to migrate data. e.g. delete or add some records. Very often you need joins for this.